# Clone last column and add it to the same table - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to create a new column in the html table at the end with a different header name and empty cells. The table has alternate rows colored.

I am trying like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>testing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function add() {
        $('#tableID tr').clone().appendTo('#tableID');
    }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="tableID">
    <tr>
        <th>one</th>
        <th>two</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="add()">add</button>
</body>
</html>
```

What changes do I need to make to achieve this while keeping alternate colors? THE `td` elements have some meta data with them so I would like to keep that too.

Comment: Do you really mean column, or do you mean the last row?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo showing how to clone the last row and last column.

The alternating row colours are preserved, the header text is changed and the `td` cells are "emptied". In addition if you inspect the html after the column has been copied, you will notice that the `data-foo="metadata"` attribute has been copied as well.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#clonerow').on('click', function() {
    $('#tableID tr').last().clone().appendTo('#tableID');
  });

  $('#clonecolumn').on('click', function() {
    $('#tableID tr :last-child').each(function() {
      var clone = $(this).clone().html('&nbsp;');
      if (clone.is('th')) {
        clone.text('header');
      }
      $(this).parent().append(clone);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#tableID tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}
#tableID tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="clonerow">Clone Row</button>
<button id="clonecolumn">Clone Column</button>
<table id="tableID">
  <tr>
    <th>one</th><th>two</th>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td data-foo="metadata">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td><td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td><td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean cloning `row`, that's pretty straightforward:

```
$("#add").on("click", function(){
    $('#tableID tr:last').clone().appendTo('#tableID');
});
```

If you want to add a `column`, that requires a bit more work, but essentially you would have to append a `<td></td>` to each `<tr>` in the table, like so:

```
$("#clone").on("click", function(){
    $("#tableID tr").each(function(){
        $(this).append("<td>Test</td>");
    });
});
```

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hw5p09xa/) to see how they both work.

Keep in mind this is only an example. You would have to determine if the row contains a `<th>` and change the content accordingly, but you get the idea.